# Apply CSS on multiple words of a title attribute

Tags: css, attributes, title

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
[title~='77'] {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <a title="One Piece vol 77 GN"> one piece vol 77</a>
  <a title="One Piece vol 78 GN"> one piece vol 78</a>
  <a title="Naruto vol 77 GN"> naruto vol 77</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have a border around one piece vol 77 only. I can't alter the HTML code, only the CSS. I can't find a way to to say the title has to contain one & 77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add unique word for border style.There are two '77' in your tittles. So you can add 'One' or 'Piece' with '77'. Here is the code :

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
[title~='Piece'][title~='77'] {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
<!-- OR -->
<!-- [title~='One'][title~='77'] -->
</style>
</head>
<body>



<a title="One Piece vol 77 GN"> one piece vol 77</a>
<a title="One Piece vol 78 GN"> one piece vol 78</a>
<a title="Naruto vol 77 GN"> naruto vol 77</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add another `[title~='']` with One.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
[title~='77'] {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
[title~='One'][title~='77'] {
    border-radius: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<a title="One Piece vol 77 GN"> one piece vol 77</a>
<a title="One Piece vol 78 GN"> one piece vol 78</a>
<a title="Naruto vol 77 GN"> naruto vol 77</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the style border-radius for the title that you want to display the border round.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
[title~='77'] {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
[title~='One'][title~='77'] {
    border-radius: 50px;
}  
</style>
</head>
<body>



<a title="One Piece vol 77 GN"> one piece vol 77</a>
<a title="One Piece vol 78 GN"> one piece vol 78</a>
<a title="Naruto vol 77 GN"> naruto vol 77</a>


</body>
</html>
```